# Envío de parametros de vista a vista en SwiftUI

Tags: swift

¡Buenas!

Vengo de desarrollar una aplicación para Android y actualmente estoy desarrollando la misma pero con Swift para Apple.

Tengo una duda, y es que en Android para pasar información de una actividad a otra, haces lo siguiente:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActividadActual, NuevaActividad);
intent.putExtra("nombre", "Pepe")
```

y ya automaticamente haces un `getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre")` en la otra actividad y ya obtienes ese valor

Mi duda es, **¿como se puede hacer este proceso en Swift?**

¡¡Gracias!!

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que intentaste con SwiftUI?

Comment: Hay muchas formas. Por medio de storyboards o simplemente sesteando la propiedad directamente sobre la instancia del `ViewController` a la cual quieres navegar.

Comment: Por ejemplo, primero instancias el view controller (Activity): `let detailViewCtrl = DetailViewController()`, luego seteas la propiedad: `defatilViewCtrl.productId = "A123"` y luego navegas: `navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewCtrl, animated: true)`.

Comment: @gugadev No hay `storyboards` en SwiftUI, que es lo que hace referencia la pregunta.

Comment: @Bicho Ya esta conseguido, en el NavigationLink, en el parametro "destination", le paso mi vista y como parametro la variable que quiero ver en la siguiente vista. Ese parametro que le paso, esta declarado previamente en la nueva vista como "@State var nombreVariable", y ya puedo usarlo porque me viene relleno de la vista anterior

Comment: @AurelioPerez sería de gran ayuda para otras personas que puedan tener tu mismo problema, que agregues el código con la solución en la zona de respuestas. Ten en cuenta que puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como solución.

Answer (score 0):

Así me funciono a mi.
Deseo pasar un listado de empresas de la vista A a la vista B

En la vista B declaro una propiedad `@State var empresas : Array<String>` antes de `var body : some View{}`...

En la vista A, tengo una variable `@State var empresas : Array<String>` tambien antes de `var body : some View{}`...

Para enviarlo, en el NavigationLink de la vista A, en el parametro destination, le paso por parametros el listado relleno:

```
NavigationLink("", destination: B(empresas: self.empresas)
```

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que uses `@State` deberás manejarte dentro de la misma View.

Por lo que si deseas utilizar diferentes Swfit.files para tus views deberás usar el protocolo [ObservableObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject/). Valiendote de las propiedas `@Published` y `@ObservedObject`.

{

`@Published` va a trackear el objeto que deaseas observar y del cual queres pasar los datos.
Por ejemplo: `@Published var posts = [Post]()` una Array de posteos en una red social. –VC 2–.

`@ObservedObject` para crear un objeto observable, en este caso sería la clase donde se encuentra la Array anterior.
Por ejemplo: `@ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()`. –VC 1–.

}

Posteriormente en VC 1 vas a utilizar `networkManager` para utilizar los datos de la Array creada en VC 2, algo como: `Text("\(networkManager.posts.title)")` o dentro de una `List` previamente pasado el OberservedObeject `Text("\(posts.title)")`.

Te dejo este [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject) para que puedas chequear las diferencias entre `@State`, `@ObservedObject`y `@EnvironmentObject`.

Como usar c/u: [State](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-stateobject-to-create-and-monitor-external-objects); [ObservedObject](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-observedobject-to-manage-state-from-external-objects); [EnvironmentObject](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views).
[Link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sharing-an-observed-object-with-a-new-view) adicional sobre como pasar estos objetos entre Views.

Answer (score 0):

Por medio de este método, tienes que identificar tus vistas por medio de un StorybordID para poderlas llamar a través de éste.
De forma resumida, se crea la variable relacionada con el StoryboardID, donde vas agregando las variables que quieres "mandar", para después mediante el `pushViewController` se ejecute la acción

```
let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "StoryboardIDViewController") as? ClassNameViewController
        viewController?.variableObjetivo = variableLocal
//La siguiente linea es equivalente en función a la que mencionas para Android
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
```